# Adding swipe functionality and a textview to a Image Slideshow Android app - Comic

Tags: java, android, android-layout, swipe-gesture

I need to add swipe functionality and a textview to a Image Slideshow Android App implementation - which is actually a comic about the life of St. Don Bosco with images that go along with the story. Gallery widget did the job but sadly now deprecated :(

I managed to do the following and navigation between images is only possible by clicking the thumbnails at the bottom:
[Screenshots](http://postimg.org/gallery/wqwmbrra/) - Genymotion

Current Java:

```
package org.dbysmumbai.donbosco;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.dbyouth_activity);

        mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    public View makeView() {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return i;
    }

    private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty_frame);
            return i;
        }

        private Context mContext;

    }

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.dbyouth000, R.drawable.dbyouth001,
            R.drawable.dbyouth001b, R.drawable.dbyouth002};

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.dbyouth000, R.drawable.dbyouth001, R.drawable.dbyouth001b,
            R.drawable.dbyouth002};

}
```

---

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <ImageSwitcher android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />

    <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:spacing="16dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Thanks for reading. Any help/links will be greatly and irrevocably appreciated :)

EDIT:

---

I'm using this code example for a viewpager.. how can I add a textview at the bottom that will detail the story

please please explain by editing this code .. Thanks a lot :)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }


}
```

---

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
    };
    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/view_pager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There were no thumbnails available with this code example and no left/right arrow to indicate swiping. I don't know to implement those. Maybe some help please?

Comment: ViewPager is used for swipe functionality in android. this is very useful lib for viewpager
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/sample

Comment: Thanks for that awesome library! It seems perfect but I don't know how to use it in my current project. Would you please edit above pasted code and show me the samplecirclesdefault layout? Please?

Answer (score 1):

Hi There !!

1. Did you try android ViewPager component?

   if not please go through [this](https://github.com/NineWorlds/serenity-android/issues/77) .Its a very useful component.It
   solved all your problems.

   [1](https://github.com/NineWorlds/serenity-android/issues/77):
   http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
2. If gallery is giving problem then go for [HorizontalScrollView](https://github.com/NineWorlds/serenity-android/issues/77)  component of android.

Comment: Thanks for answering! :) I tried this [project](https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Android-HorizontalScrollView) and it does not have swipe functionality and the "previous","next" buttons do not always refresh themselves after navigation. :( Is there any way to edit my current code to implement viewpager with a textview at the bottom? I'm not very good at java :(

Answer (score 0):

This project is divided in to three tasks. First one is building Grid View display of all the images. Second is showing selected grid image in full screen slider. And finally adding pinch zooming functionality to fullscreen image.

Check out [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/) tutorial, may be helpful for you to achieve your target

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) Actually, this project is very simple and it does not require the GridView and Pinch Zooming functionality. Is it possible to "dumb down" that tutorial somehow and only implement the current basic requirements? - That would be awesome! :D